# Should Nitro pull in manual changes to todo.txt?

Tags: task-management, nitro

I was very happy to find that Nitro created a todo.txt containing the tasks I added in the application. I like editing a todo.txt manually. However, after doing so (and syncing) it appears that Nitro does not pick up the changes. Is this expected behaviour? Is it impossible to have a workflow incorporating both editing tasks in Nitro and with a text editor in todo.txt?

Comment: Nitro? Please explain what it is and where you've got it from. I don't see any package in the official repositories by that name.

Comment: @gertvdijk It is available in the Ubuntu Software Centre -- but I think in the Independent repo: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nitro/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted a support request to the developer, and I received the following clarification by email:

> Hi,
>
> It's expected behaviour. We're currently working on mobile apps and
>   the todo.txt was just a thing so you can view it on your phone. Sorry
>   about that.
>
> Thanks, Jono